# Geog vs. Geom - not same results

Tags: sql-server-spatial

I have these two SQL Server 2008 R2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OIS_NOA_Buffers WHERE geog.STIntersects(geography::Point(35.25934, -120.64432, 4326))=1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OIS_NOA_Buffers WHERE geom.STIntersects(geometry::Point(35.25934, -120.64432, 4326))=1;
```

The first returns a 1 and the second a 0. Both geog and geom are SRID 4326.

Geog geometry was derived from Set geog = Geom.STAsText()

Why wouldn't they both return 1?  (The point is under the polygons.)

Comment: I disagree - mine was a rooky mistake about mixing up lat/long and XY - the other post was about ??? - way to complex to find my mistake. Certainly from the starting point of the OP there would be no way to run a search that pointed to the referenced post.

Comment: You're right and it's my fault. I made two errors - first I misread the question as being about making a calculation (or confused myself in searching for possible duplicates, which btw was found by searching on "geography geometry"), so I was thinking the issue was geog vs geom and the equations used. Second, I'm pretty sure I posted the wrong link when I put in my dupe question nomination. I believe the original flag was to close as off-topic due to the issue being a typo. cc @mapperz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Parcels..OIS_NOA_Buffers WHERE geog.STIntersects(geography::Point(35.25934, -120.64432, 4326))=1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Parcels..OIS_NOA_Buffers WHERE geom.STIntersects(geometry::Point(-120.64432, 35.25934, 4326))=1;
```

STIntersects for geography uses Lat/Long while for geometry it uses X/Y (long/lat.)